# Laravel join two tables on Json Column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables(models), one with a json column that may contain the id on other table. I want to join these two together, how do i chain a laravel join to my query.

Comment: Have u checked [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#json-where-clauses)

Comment: Doesn’t work for joins

Comment: @Jigs1212 That helped! And json-inner-join works after some chages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO it turns out the join wasn't working because the json column was storing the id field as a string and the joined table's id is stored as an integer.
Casting the result into an integer fixed this. Let's say table 'a' is the first table that contains a json column with an id on second table which is table 'b'.So I did.

```
DB::table('a')->join('b','b.id',DB::Raw("CAST(a.data->'$.id' AS UNSIGNED)"))->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply the JSON logic inside the join query like:

```
Post::select('posts.id', 'posts.field1','posts.field2','samples.id as sample_id', ..)
        ->join('samples', 'posts.json_col_name.id', '=', 'samples.id')
        ->get();
```

Make sure that you make no conflict for the query builder while picking columns (use `field_name as another_name`) when both models have fields with common name.

Comment: I think  'posts->json_col_name_id' should be 'posts.json_col_name->id'. From the question though, just one table has the json column, not both.

Comment: Ok, the question is too short and I was reading the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#json-where-clauses) says about *JSON Where Clauses*. Edited!